# React component isn't updating on socket.io event

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I cannot figure out why my React component is not updating once the viewer count changes. When the page first renders, the amount is displayed correctly. Socket events are logged to my terminal also just fine.

There is probably an easy fix to this. What am I doing wrong?

### Server

```js
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketIo = require('socket.io');

const port = process.env.PORT || 4001;
const index = require('./index');

const app = express();
app.use(index);

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('+ client connected');
  getApiAndEmit(socket);

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('- Client disconnected');
    getApiAndEmit(socket);
  });
});

const getApiAndEmit = (socket) => {
  socket.emit('event', io.engine.clientsCount);
};

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

### React

```js
import React from 'react';
import socketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      response: false,
      endpoint: 'http://localhost:4001',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { endpoint } = this.state;

    const socket = socketIOClient(endpoint);

    socket.on('event', (data) => this.setState({ response: data }));
  }

  render() {
    const { response } = this.state;

    return (
      <p>{response ? <p>Active Users {response}</p> : <p>Loading...</p>}</p>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're using the wrong type of emit. Take a look at this cheat sheet: https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/

If you use `socket.emit()`, socketio only sends the event to the single, connected client, if you use `socket.broadcast.emit()`, it emits the event to every client except the sender, and if you use `io.emit()`, it emits the event to every client.

So I think your code should look something like:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  io.emit('event', io.engine.clientsCount);

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('event', io.engine.clientsCount);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { endpoint } = this.state;

    const socket = socketIOClient(endpoint);
    let self = this;

    socket.on('event', (data) => self.setState({ response: data }));
  }
```

Comment: Doesn't this help you? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33940894/13094317)

Comment: It was a server issue, not frontend, thanks though!